# It is possible to run winforms application on Repberry Pi 2?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mono, raspberry-pi2

I trying to run winforms application under Windows IoT, Rapberry Pi 2 by using System.Windows.Forms. So, it's possible?
**UPDATE 1**
Just for better understanding, I have digital signage application. It's build with winforms, and I trying to run it.

Comment: Ive heard of Pi's running winrt, so I dont see why not

Comment: Not sure about the Windows.Forms namespace being available under IoT, may need to be a Windows Universal app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. 
On a Raspberry pi running Windows 10, you can only run UWP apps.

Comment: @Renan OP isnt asking about mono, OP is asking about Windows IoT

Comment: And you would also have to run winforms on Mono, which, in itself, is answered on the mono forum page: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/ but as stated, the original question was about Raspberry PI on Windows

Comment: @Wobbles oh sorry I somehow hadn't noticed that.